# Django model default

Tags: django, django-models

I add "default=OtherModel.get_first()" to my model, and did a "python manage.py makemigrations", and I'm getting the following error. How can I get around this?

```
 File "/opt/titan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 464, in serialize
    "topics/migrations/#migration-serializing" % (value, get_docs_version())
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <ConventionTypes: HY - Half Year>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
For more, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing


class MyModel(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel, blank=False, null=False, default=OtherModel.get_first())
```

Comment: Did you read the article it tells you to?

Comment: I just read it, and it's not related to my problem.

Comment: Not even with the method it tells you to write?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def get_default():
    return OtherModel.get_first()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel, blank=False, null=False, default=get_default)
```

You can also just hardcode *pk* but it's ugly.